# Typescript enumeration instance type

Tags: typescript

This must be something extremelly simple but couldn't find the words to search here on stackoverflow.

Basically I would like to be able to typehint a variable being of an enumeration type. Something like this:

```
enum RecurringEventDeleteOptions {
  THIS_EVENT = 1,
  THIS_AND_FUTURE_EVENTS = 2,
  ALL_EVENTS = 3,
}

const foo: RecurringEventDeleteOptions = RecurringEventDeleteOptions;
```

I get an error from the variable `foo` (`Type 'typeof RecurringEventDeleteOptions' is not assignable to type 'RecurringEventDeleteOptions'`)

Is there a way to tell that foo will be of type `RecurringEventDeleteOptions`?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDGYBOSCWIDmBRAbqALgCLAA2w%20wA8gA76oD2IAzlAN4BQUUAKgBICSAZQD6WAGpYActygBeKAEYANJx4CRAQUmFhAMQCq3fTCyiJ0wXKgAmFVw0AZB2andL8gMwqAvu3bxGJnwoAEMALlgEZDRMXAJiMgoaOkCrOEQUdGw8ECJScipaBmYAbnYgA)

Why? Because I have a VueJS template that will have to access these options. An example:

```
<template>
  <div> {{ foo.THIS_EVENT }} </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

@Component
export default class FooClass extends Vue {
  public foo = RecurringEventDeleteOptions;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to store the type of the enumeration, and not a value of it, you simply have to add typeof:

```js
const a: typeof RecurringEventDeleteOptions = RecurringEventDeleteOptions;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should assign one concrete value of the enum to that variable, for example:

```
const a: RecurringEventDeleteOptions = RecurringEventDeleteOptions.THIS_EVENT;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDGYBOSCWIDmBRAbqALgCLAA2w+wA8gA76oD2IAzlAN4BQUUAKgBICSAZQD6WAGpYActygBeKAEYANJx4CRAQUmFhAMQCq3fTCyiJ0wXKgAmFVw0AZB2andL8gMwqAvu3bxGJnwoAEMALlgEZDRMXAJiMgoaOkCrOEQUdGw8ECJScipaBmYAOj4hF2kAbn9A4IAjNKjM2Jy8xMKU0sdncVdBGoDmejISknoMAAoAcnCoaagAalCASkHAkeAxiZn6iIXl+rX2IA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What Im looking for is to say that variable is of the enumeration type. I'm looking specifically for this since I have a VueJS template component that needs to access those `RecurringEventDeleteOptions`. I will update the question to show what I mean